# Why can't "your communities" be edited on mobile?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, stack-exchange-button

Using (the latest) Firefox on Android (6.0.1) there's no "edit" link to the right of "Your Communities" which is present on the full site. This may be by design, although it's not clear why having the ability to search for text and then click "add" and then "save" is deemed to be any more problematic for mobile users than desktop ones.

Comment: The 404s will be fixed as of next build (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294673/more-stack-exchange-communities-link-broken), so I've edited your post down to the other remaining issue.