# "More Stack Exchange Communities" link broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, 404-not-found

On the mobile view, the top-left navigation menu has a header which is also a link titled "More Stack Exchange Communities":

> [image]

This link is broken; it goes to https://meta.stackexchange.com/sites which is 404.

"Your Communities" is also broken. It looks like maybe the links are using the domain `meta.stackexchange.com` where they should be `stackexchange.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops. Yeah, when the view was updated as part of the HTTPS-related work, `Site.MetaStackExchange` crept in in place of `Site.StackExchange`.

I pushed a fix; it'll go out with the next prod build.